# Custom Keras loss function in R with case_when in function

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, loss-function, loss

I try to build a custom loss function for my Keras model. My dataset has two values in the class variable, namely 1 and 2. I would like to optimize my model in the ability to optimize to recognize 1 correctly. In this context it is not relevant whether it recognizes 2 correct or not.

Thus, when the matching variable is 2 it gets a score of 0 and the same is the case when it matches class 1 correct. In case it does not match class 1 correct it gets a score of 1.

```
library(keras)
library(tidyverse)    
OneOnly <- function(y_true, y_pred) {
  K <- backend()
  K$mean(
    case_when(
      y_true == 2 ~ 0,
      y_true == 1 & y_pred == 1 ~ 0,
      TRUE ~ 1
    )
  )
}
```

When I try to train my model with this loss function I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Evaluation error: LHS of case 1 (`y_true == 2`) must be a logical, not environment.
```

From the error message, I do understand that I am not able to include variables like 1 and 2 in in the checks. Does anybody have a suggestion on how to mitigate this?

Comment: I have found a workable work around solution using weights. This has helped me to balance the results.